# Razor ASP.NET: Show data from 'if' inside 'foreach'. 'break;' doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net, if-statement, razor, foreach

I'm having the following situation (in razor using ASP.NET):

```
@if(@groups.Users != null)
{
    @foreach(var user in @groups.Users)
    {
        @if(@user.UserId == VALUE)
        {
            CASE 01
            break;
        }
    }
    CASE 02

}
else
{
SHOW CASE 02
}
```

So all I want is CASE 01 if the Value is in the collection of @user.UserId. And else display CASE02.

But, because if there are no users in the group, then it should display CASE02 too. Pretty simple I thought.

Now this does not work (after it shows CASE 01, it also shows the CASE02(because of the else). Else the code works fine.

I tried putting another 'break;' after the CASE 02 in the if statement, but then it cuts off my code?

I think I'm just missing something here ...

I hope I explained it right?
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your attempt is not working because the `break` breaks out of the foreach loop, but the code execution continues on the line after the loop (where you've put CASE 02)

A clean way to do this correctly is to use LINQ:

```
@if (groups.Users != null && groups.Users.Any(u => u.UserId == VALUE))
{
    CASE 01
}
else
{
    CASE 02
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. I didn't know about the '.Any'. Thank you!